# How to filter json data in filebeat yml file

Tags: filebeat

While using kafka input, I want to output only when json data contains a specific string.

I tried setting "include_lines" in filebeat.yml, but it was not filtered properly.

When the filebit.yml setting is as follows and data-set1 and 2 are input, not only data-set1 but also data-set2 are output.

I expected only data-set 1 to be output, but it wasn't.

What did I make a mistake?

- part of the filebeat.yml

  ```
  filebeat.inputs:
  - type: kafka
    hosts:
      - qa-parkbae-01.hanpda.com:9092,
      - qa-parkbae-02.hanpda.com:9092,
      - qa-parkbae-03.hanpda.com:9092
    topics: ["parkbae-test-topic1"]
    group_id: "test123"
    ssl.enabled: false

    include_lines: ['\"event\":\"basket\"']
  ```
- input data-set1 :
  {"id":"parkbae","event":"basket","data":"test1"}
- input data-set2 :
  {"id":"parkbae","event":"ball","data":"test2"}

Comment: i'm interested in that, did you find an answer ?